# bootstrap tabs dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, event-handling

I'm making the transition to jquery 1.9 and using .on, In the past I've relied way too much on .live() and of course life was great, now things once again seem really complicated.

I'm trying to load dynamic content into some bootstrap tabs.  but with .on I can't figure out how to trigger an ajax call when #ticketnotes is shown.

Html is as follows:

```
<div class="tabbable ticket_tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tickettabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#ticketreplies" data-toggle="tab">Replies</a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="tabtickets" href="#ticketnotes" data-toggle="tab">Ticket Notes</a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#timetrackticket" data-toggle="tab">Time Track</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="ticketreplies">
            $body
            $replyForm
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="ticketnotes">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="loader" style="display:none;">
            </div>
        </div>
        $replyForm
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="timetrackticket">
        <div class="well">time track info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded, the "ticket replies" are already there, but seeing as how i want to keep loading times to a minimum, i rather load all associated data separately, viewing a ticket doesn't necessarily mean that someone is going to go through the notes, therefor no need to load it right away.

my last attempt looked something like:

```
$('#tickettabs').on('show', '.tabtickets', function(){
    if($('#ticketnotes').is(":visible")){
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

needless to say, it never said hi.

running the exact same if condition in firefox works as it should.  So i'm pretty confident that the problem lies with how i'm trying to bind the event handler.

I thank you in advance for assisting in saving whats left of my sanity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because by the time the show event is fired, the browser may not have got time to repaint the dom.

A possible solution to this is to use a timeout function with 0 delay.

```
$('#tickettabs').on('show', '.tabtickets', function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if($('#ticketnotes').is(":visible")){
        alert("hi");
    }
  }, 0)
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fqGUGY?p=preview)

Another solution is to check which tab header was clicked

```
$('#tickettabs').on('show', '.tabtickets', function(e){
  if($(this).has('a.tabtickets')){
    alert('has tabtickets')
  }
});
```

Comment: ok that worked, im extremely grateful and dont mean for this to sound bad at all, but why did that work?  I dont understand how setting a timeout on an event got it to do what it needs to.  I thought that was 1 of the things they tried to accomplish with .on and adding the event listener into the call.

Comment: It is because since we are using `setTimeout` the javascript execution will be delayed till current execution scope is completed which will give the browser enough time to refresh the dom with the changes applied to it

Comment: @Mike which solution are you going with

Comment: @Mike on a side not, there was nothing wrong with your `on` event registration, it was the `if` statement that was failing

Comment: I didn't think about it timing out at all, since the tab is in the DOM at all times, the thought of a delay never occurred to me.  I tested the if condition by running it in firefox by it self, and it worked. so that lead me to think it was .on.  but all is well now. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the best approch:

```
//the reason for the odd-looking selector is to listen for the click event
// on links that don't even exist yet - i.e. are loaded from the server.
$('#tabs').on('click','.tablink,#prodTabs a',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");

    if (typeof url !== "undefined") {
        var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;

        // ajax load from data-url
        $(href).load(url,function(result){      
            pane.tab('show');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
```

Use a .tablink class on your in-content links to link between tabs. See comment in JS.
HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_basic">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_images" data-url="?action=images">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_videos" data-url="?action=videos">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_basic" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        <div id="tab_images" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        <div id="tab_videos" class="tab-pane active"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Original: https://coderwall.com/p/1lnxba/load-bootstrap-tabs-dynamically
Adapted: http://www.bootply.com/63891